# Specifying array of functions with unknown arguments throws a typeerror

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-testing-library

I've set-up a rather simple hook called `useField.ts`, which is defined in the following manner:

```
type CheckFunction = <T>(input: T, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown

export const useField = <T>(
   input: T,
   ...checkFunctions: CheckFunction[]
) => {
  // .... and the code goes here, but irrelevant for the question
}
```

Afterwards I've begun writing my tests in `useField.test.tsx` in the following way:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { useField } from '../useField'

describe('useField error functions', () => {
 
  const emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/gi
  const isValidEmail = (input: string): boolean => !!input.match(emailRegex)

  test('Basic checkFunction', () => {
     const { result } = renderHook(() => useField('valid@email.com', isValidEmail)
     // ^ I get a type-error here
  })
})
```

The line where I try to pass the `isValidEmail` function has the following [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) error:

```
Argument of type '(input: string) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CheckFunction'.
  Types of parameters 'input' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Now this could be technically solved by assigning the definition of `checkFunctions` to `any` but it's something I want to be wary of as it kind of defeats the purpose of type-checking.

*I also thought about using a generic, but issue is, the arguments can be of various types and that can't be expressed by an array of a single generic*

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Because from a logical standpoint the usage of `unknown` seems correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your check functions only accept one argument, why do you define it as accepting multiple values? E.g. the `...args: unknown[]`. You'd also specify that it returns a `boolean` instead of just `unknown`.

You can do something like this, which actually uses a generic but seems to work fine for your use case, as far as I can tell:

```
export const useField = <T>(
    input: T,
    ...checkFunctions: Array<(value: T) => boolean>
) => {
    // .... and the code goes here, but irrelevant for the question
}

const result = useField('someString', validator1, validator2);
// ^ It would know T is a string here, since the input is a string
// Therefore it'll check that `validator1` is of the type `(value: string) => boolean`
const result = useField('someString', str => {
    // TypeScript knows the type of `str` is string
    return str.includes('something');
});
// This would error:
const result = useField<string>(123, validator1);
// As well as this due to the validator accepting the wrong value:
const result = useField('string', (value: number) => true);
```

This is assuming that `useField` expects the actual inputted value, and not the id/name of an `<input>` element. Otherwise there's no reason to have `input` be generic (after all, the name/id is always a string) and you wouldn't name an `<input>` `valid@email.com` but `email` instead.

---

***For the updated code in the question.***

You're defining your "generic" `CheckFunction` type incorrectly. Use this instead:

```
type CheckFunction<T> = (input: T, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown

export const useField = <T>(
    input: T,
    ...checkFunctions: CheckFunction<T>[]
) => {
    // .... and the code goes here, but irrelevant for the question
}
```

Your version, where you use `type Type = <T>(...` basically tells TypeScript "this function has *a* generic type but it doesn't matter outside `Type`". While if you use `type Type<T>`, you tell TypeScript that that type matters, e.g. it should be specified by the user of the type.

In short, by using `type Type<T>` you allow your `useField` to specify what `T` inside `Type` represents, e.g. the same type as `useField`'s `T`.

Comment: Because it's gonna be for a package and I need to leave a leeway for the user to pass multiple arguments and results returns (e.g. return which throws `error` (void) is still considered valid. Just like a function with the arguments `(input, '>=', 20) => {//...}` needs to be a valid checkFunction by definiton. Which is also why I didn't use the generics as mentioned in the original post. So here the arguments have different types and there are multiple of them (hence the type set to `...args: unknown[]`, as we do not know amount of arguments.

Comment: The `throw ...` statement doesn't care what the function's return type is. After all, if the function throws, it doesn't actually return anything. As for your last example, I think you want to do `useField(input, '>=', 20, expressionValidator)` or something? How would you differentiate between the arguments and the validators? _Assuming I want to be able to pass a function as an argument to another validator, e.g. `useField(input, '<=', validateEmail, validateArrayWithValidator)`.

Comment: I should have probably specified *(and in retrospect even type-defined)*, the first arguments will always be of the input type. So now, that I think about, the definition should be more something akin to `type CheckFunction = <T>(input: T, ...args?: unknown[]) => unknown`, this however still leaves me with an error "`Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'`"

Comment: Can you update the question with the updated code and error? Having trouble figuring out what you exactly did (and therefore what the error is about)

Comment: absolutely. there you go :-) I'm super confused as to why it doesn't work not though. Because I would understand if it had issues with the `...args` spread, but I didn't expect ts to throw an error about the generic as well.

Comment: Oooops, right, I mixed up the `type X<T> = () =>` with `type X = <T>() =>` you are correct. Thanks a lot :-)